# javascript: Two AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am having the following code:
The first function fun() is called on click on select, it is working perfectly.
But the second function fun1() is called on click on a submit button, but In the second function the URL(ax/setexmsess.jsp) is not accessed.
If any one can give me the solution.. Thank you very much..

```
<script>
function fun(){
           var e = document.getElementById("s1");
           var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
               var xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject){
                xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            if (xmlHttp==null){
                alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
                return;
            }
            var url="ax/getqt.jsp";
            url +="?sel=" +strUser;
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){
                document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            }
            }
            xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
        function fun1(){  

            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
                var xmlHttpf= new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject){
                xmlHttpf= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            if (xmlHttpf==null){
                alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
                return;
            }
            var url="ax/setexmsess.jsp";
            xmlHttpf.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (xmlHttpf.readyState==4 || xmlHttpf.readyState=="complete"){

            }
            }
            xmlHttpf.open("POST", url, true);

            xmlHttpf.send(null);

        }
</script>
```

The Html code is like this:

```
<select name="s1" id="s1" class="text" onclick="fun();">
         <option value="">--Select--</option>
               <c:forEach items="${rs.rows}" var="row">
                  <option value="${row.testid}">${row.testname}</option>
               </c:forEach>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Start" class="button2" onclick="fun1();"/>
```

The problem is that as soon as I hit the submit button, I have to set a session attribute, the page in url is just for setting that session attribute.. If you have any another way of doing it, please suggest me.

One more thing, The function fun1() is working, but it is not calling the given url.

Comment: The two pieces of code look similar. Are you sure the event is called correctly from the button? Also, you might want to wrap this ajax call in a separate function, instead of copying the entire code every time.

Comment: you have to put your html code as well, if you want to allow us to help you.

Comment: I have pasted my html code too... Please have a look on it

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that the problem is using `submit` button, if you change:

```
<input type="submit" value="Start" class="button2" onclick="fun1();"/>
```

to

```
<input type="button" value="Start" class="button2" onclick="fun1();"/>
```

your problem would probably get solved, because submit buttons have a default behavior to submit the current form. the other way you have is to prevent submit behavior using `event.preventDefault();` in your form `onsubmit` event, in older browsers you should probably do `return false;` or set `event.returnValue` to `false`.

Comment: The problem is that as soon as I hit the submit button, I have to set a session attribute, the page in url is just for setting that session attribute.. If you have any another way of doing it, please suggest me.

Comment: One more thing, The function fun1() is working, but it is not calling the given url.